# Error when logging in with webgoat on Kali

Tags: java, tomcat

I've installed tomcat7 on the Linux distribution Kali (via apt-get) and downloaded the latest webgoat release from: https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat/releases/download/7.0.1/webgoat-container-7.0.1.war
into the webapp directory.

Besides I've added the tomcat user for webgoat as described here: https://deepakdevanand.wordpress.com/2015/05/25/installing-webgoat-on-kali-linux/

Following the URL localhost:8080/webgoat-container-7.0.1/attack leads to the start page where I can login with the user webgoat.
Btw. the tutorial says I should use my own configured tomcat user with username "webgoat" and password "Sec3rt" but the webpage shows that the default admin username is "webgoat" with the password "webgoat".

When logging in there appears an error message:

```
Error Message: Could not initialize class org.owasp.webgoat.session.UserTracker
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.owasp.webgoat.session.UserTracker
at org.owasp.webgoat.session.Screen.getLessonTracker(Screen.java:117)
at org.owasp.webgoat.lessons.LessonAdapter.makeSuccess(LessonAdapter.java:251)
at org.owasp.webgoat.plugin.HowToWork.createContent(HowToWork.java:53)
at org.owasp.webgoat.lessons.AbstractLesson.handleRequest(AbstractLesson.java:868)
at org.owasp.webgoat.HammerHead.makeScreen(HammerHead.java:332)
at org.owasp.webgoat.HammerHead.doPost(HammerHead.java:148)
at org.owasp.webgoat.HammerHead.doGet(HammerHead.java:104)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The tomcat logfile lists the same error:

```
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Apr 08, 2016 8:27:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Apr 08, 2016 8:27:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: WebGoat is starting
Apr 08, 2016 8:27:47 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Adding extra mappings for lessions
Apr 08, 2016 8:27:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
Apr 08, 2016 8:43:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/webgoat-container-7.0.1] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.owasp.webgoat.session.UserTracker] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.owasp.webgoat.session.UserTracker
```

Comment: A NoClassDefFoundError with message `Could not initialize class XYZ` normally indicates that the JVM has already tried and failed to load the class `XYZ`.  Are there any other exceptions in the log before the one above, in particular any `ExceptionInInitializerError`s?

Comment: Is there any webgoat log file I could check? I am logging in as user webgoat. java info:
java version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3)  (7u91-2.6.3-1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: That tutorial is out of date, as WebGoat has undergone major architectural changes between versions 5.4 and 7.0.1.  I would say that there is no need to edit tomcat-users.xml as recommended by the tutorial.  Secondly, there should be other log files under the Tomcat logs folder.  In particular try looking in the `webgoat_main.log` file.

Comment: There is no file "webgoat_main.log". Only catalina log files and localhost log files. I tried https://s3.amazonaws.com/webgoat-war/webgoat-container-7.0.1-war-exec.jar now with an integrated tomcat and it works. The Easy run is described here: https://github.com/WebGoat/WebGoat

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a while myself. It's possible that you are missing permissions to write the user database file. If your log entries show something like this:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/tomcat7/UserDatabase.mv.db (Permission denied)
```

Then it would be a matter of granting your tomcat user permissions to the folder listed.